# Google Drive gets stuck on creating a zip file when I try to download an entire folder

Tags: google-drive, bulk-download

I'm trying to download an entire folder from the Google Drive website:

[image: download an entire folder]

However, it gets stuck at the "zipping" stage and doesn't proceed to download:

[image: stuck at "zipping" stage]

This happens whether it's a large folder or a small folder, with either many or few files.

What is getting stuck?  How can I fix this?

---

I've had this problem for quite a while, across multiple reboots.  I'm using the latest version of Chrome on the most updated version of Windows 10.

Comment: Have you restarted your computer? What is the network speed when you try to download the folders? Is your browser on the latest version? Please edit your question with these answers. Also, which browser are you using, and have you tried an alternative browser? It could be helpful to tell us the operating system as well.

Comment: Try using another web browser, another computer and network. If the problem persist contact a Google Drive specialist from https://support.google.com/drive

Answer (score -4):

If you want to know how to fix Google Drive not downloading files after zipping, check out this video > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r26JGqtnD4I